# C# 8 Nullable Reference Types - [NotNullWhen(bool)] with async Task<bool>

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

Given is the following code:

```cs
private async Task NotNullTestAsync(bool fakeSyncParameter, bool fakeAsyncParameter)
{
    // SYNC
    var syncValue = fakeSyncParameter ? null : (int?)0;

    if (!this.NotNullWhenTrueSync(syncValue))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Works...
    Debug.WriteLine(syncValue.Value);

    // ASYNC
    var asyncValue = fakeAsyncParameter ? null : (int?)0;
    var asyncResult = await this.NotNullWhenTrueAsync(asyncValue).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (!asyncResult)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Nullable value type may be null "error"
    Debug.WriteLine(asyncValue.Value);
}

private bool NotNullWhenTrueSync([NotNullWhen(true)]int? value)
{
    return value.HasValue;
}

private async Task<bool> NotNullWhenTrueAsync([NotNullWhen(true)]int? value)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(value.HasValue).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I would expect that the async approach works like the sync approach but it's not :(

Am I doing something wrong or are `async return` types not supported for the `[NotNullWhen(true)]` attribute?

Comment: I guess that's because the return type isn't `bool`, but `Task<bool>`. You can tell the compiler that YOU know that something is not null using the `!` operator. On the other hand, how did you come up with this code?

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek thanks, I just found a similar code on a recent code review and was wondering why it does not work if you append the NotNullWhen to the property.

You gave me the right hint, I've the solution somewhere back in my mind... I will answer my own question if I got the solution...

It was something like "Do validation checks in synchronous methods and then call your async methods. Otherwise you can have unexpected behaviours with exceptions thrown in your async method."

Comment: Right now, nullable reference types do not work terribly well with generics, and that includes `Task<T>`.